# Assign elastic ip to ec2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have a linux (centos 7) ec2-instance that has been running for a while now.

I added a elastic IP to the server but for some reason cannot connect on port 22

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/elastic-ip-addresses-eip.html#using-instance-addressing-eips-allocating

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/elastic-ip-addresses-eip.html#using-instance-addressing-eips-associating

Following the links above I am able to see the new Elastic IP I added, however when changing to a security group that has 22 tcp 0.0.0.0/0 i cannot ssh.

What am I missing?

Comment: Has the server been configured to listen for connections on that port? Can you connect using other ports?

Comment: @Tim yes I can ssh on the private IP address

Comment: Did the server have public address prior to this.  If not, is it in a public subnet?

Comment: @kenlukas No it was not on a public subnet, working now

Comment: If it's working please answer your own question. Also note I asked if you could connect to another port on that EIP, rather than the private IP